# why is python calling my /etc/zshrc when opening and why am I getting "no key sequence terminator" errors

Tags: python, r, macos, zshrc, macos-monterey

I'm getting some strange behavior when I open up a python or R interactive session.
Eg for python:

```
>python
Python 3.10.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jun 14 2022, 07:09:13) [Clang 13.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

readline: /etc/zshrc: line 9: fi: no key sequence terminator

readline: /etc/zshrc: line 16: HISTSIZE=2000: no key sequence terminator

readline: /etc/zshrc: line 17: SAVEHIST=1000: no key sequence terminator

readline: /etc/zshrc: line 26: else: no key sequence terminator

readline: /etc/zshrc: line 60: fi: no key sequence terminator

readline: /etc/zshrc: line 9: fi: no key sequence terminator

readline: /etc/zshrc: line 16: HISTSIZE=2000: no key sequence terminator

readline: /etc/zshrc: line 17: SAVEHIST=1000: no key sequence terminator

readline: /etc/zshrc: line 26: else: no key sequence terminator

readline: /etc/zshrc: line 60: fi: no key sequence terminator

readline: /etc/zshrc: line 60: fi: no key sequence terminator
```

Moreoever, in terms of functionality, I find that, when I press certain keys on the keyboard, I get bell sounds and no output. So for instance, when I type "e" I get two bell sounds and the output "":h" (between the outer inverted commas).

Why is this happening and what should I do to fix it?

UPDATE:

I tried renaming my /etc/zshrc file so that it wouldn't be available for R/Python sessions to run.

I copied the content from it to my ~/.zshrc file.

I no longer get the "no key sequence terminator" errors on opening.

But now, in R, when I press the key "e", I find that I get an endless repetition of

```
":history-s":history-s":history-s":history-s"
```

In python I get something more informative: a shorter sequence followed by

```
":history-s":history-sreadline: maximum macro execution nesting level exceeded
```

Comment: Is `python` an alias for some other command?

Comment: Do you have a `.pystartup` file in your home dir, and/or a `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable?

Comment: echo $PYTHONSTARTUP yields nothing and I can't find a .pystartup file. This happens regardless of whether I am in a conda environment. Both python and python3 sessions both produce the same error.

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your readline config. See what `echo $INPUTRC` prints, and if you have a `~/.inputrc` file, see what's in there.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my ~/.inputrc file had the following code:

```
$include /etc/zshrc

export "\C-p":history-search-backward
export "\C-n":history-search-forward
```

I noticed that the letter "e" in export had different linting to the rest of the word "export".

Getting rid of all three lines worked.

In my ~/.zshrc file, I replaced the export lines with

```
bindkey '^P' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '^N' history-beginning-search-forward
```